# Datagridview image column refresh issue

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I have issue with refreshing image column in a DataGridView. First of all I am getting information from a database and I am populating my DataGridView with no problem.

This is the code to populate it:

```
dgpointsnc.Rows.Clear();   

DBEngine db = new DBEngine(); //This is simply an object that I use to communicate with the database
string query;

query = @"SELECT * FROM tpointncp";
db.ExecuteSelectQuery(query,"tpoints");

for(int i=0; i<db.DtSet.Tables["tpoints"].Rows.Count;i++)
{
   string path = db.DtSet.Tables["tpoints"].Rows[i]["image"].ToString();

   if(path == "")
   {
       path = @"Z:\Qualité\ImagePourquois\gear.png";
   }

   dgpointsnc.Rows.Add(Image.FromFile(path),"test","test");
}
```

Here is an image representing this:

[image]

Then, I allow the user to modify the image of the selected row through individual form. This step working well.

So, after the modification done, I repopulate the DataGridView with the same method that I used to do it the first time. **The problem I have is all the list items refresh well, but the "Image Column" keeps the old image and add the new one in front of it** :

[image]

I don't know why it keeps the old one while the rest of the list is refreshing.

Guys, I think the problem is not when I populate the datagridview; I tried to add more data to my table.

**Result when I am scrolling :**

[image]

Any idea what can do that ?

Comment: try setting the image to the cell this way _dgpointsnc.Rows.Cell[cellname].value = image;_

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but it don't work, still doing what I described. But I tried to add .Value = null before, but no sucess too.

Comment: I guess the datagridview is binded. If so are you updating the image in the source or directly in the dgv?

Comment: I am updating the image directly in the source (database), and then I repopulate it with the fresh new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Vinc's [earlier edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16738294/3) the issue is that:

> when you set the property "ImageLayout" of the Image Column to "Stretch", it creates that problem